# Why can't I connect to a Sql Server with PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, apache

I wrote code as below:

```
<?php
    $conn = mssql_connect("xx.xx.xx.xx", "username", "password") 
            or die("Can't connect to server ".mssql_error());
    echo "Success";
    mssql_close($conn);
?>
```

The error is:

> PHP Warning: mssql_connect()
>   [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to
>   connect to server: xx.xx.xx.xx in
>   xxxxxxx\conn.php
>   on line 2 PHP Fatal error: Call to
>   undefined function mssql_error() in
>   xxxxxxx\conn.php
>   on line 3

The server is Apache2.2, the version of Sql Server is 2005, the version of PHP is 5.2.5, and I remove the `;` before `extension=php_mssql.dll` and there is a `php_mssql.dll` in the `ext` directory

Comment: There is no `mssql_error` function. There's an [`mssql_get_last_message`](http://php.net/mssql_get_last_message), but better would be to switch to [SqlSrv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx). As for why the connect failed, it could be blocked by a firewall, or TCP/IP may not be enabled for the SQL Server, or remote access may not be allowed by the account you're using. There isn't enough information to say.

Comment: Looks like support for [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) was added to [SqlSrv 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff628175.aspx). I'd go with that over the old mssql or procedural SqlSrv extension anyday.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your apache log if there is a problem with the mssql extension when the service starts?

Comment: It says that the extension can't be found

Comment: Then check with phpinfo() the extension path - perhaps it is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Use **[mssql_get_last_message()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-get-last-message.php)**

```
<?php
    $conn = mssql_connect("xx.xx.xx.xx", "username", "password") 
            or die("Can't connect to server ".mssql_get_last_message());
    echo "Success";
    mssql_close($conn);
?>
```